# GAE MapReduce Huge Query

Tags: google-app-engine, mapreduce, entity, syndication

Abstract: Is MapReduce a good idea when processing a collection of data from the database, instead of finding some answer to a somewhat complex (or just big) question?

I would like to sync a set of syndication sources (e.g. urls like http://xkcd.com/rss.xml ), which are stored in GAE's datastore as a collection/table. I see two options, one is straight forward. Make simple tasks which you put in a queue, where each task handle's 100 or 1000 or whatever natural number seems to fit in each task. The other option is MapReduce.

In the latter case, the Map does everything, and the Reduce does nothing. Moreover, the map has no result, it just alters the 'state' (of the datastore).

```java
@Override public void map(Entity entity) {
    String url = (String)entity.getProperty("url");
    for(Post p : www.fetchPostsFromFeed(url)) {
        p.save();
    }
}
```

As you can see, one source can map to many posts, so my map might as well be called "Explode".

So no emits and nothing for reduce to do. The reason I like this map-approach, is that I tell google: Here, take my collection/table, split it however you see fit to different mappers, and then store the posts wherever you like. The datastore uses 'high replication'. So availability of the data is high and a best choice for what 'computational unit' does what entity doesn't really reduce network communication. The same goes for the save of the posts, as they need to go to all datastore units. What I do like is that mapreduce has some way of fault-recovery for map-computations that get stuck, and that it knows how many tasks to send to which node, instead of queueing some number of entities somewhere hoping it makes sense.

Maybe my way of thinking here is wrong, in which case, please correct me. Anyhow, is this approach 'wrong' for the lack of reduce and map being an 'explode'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, Map pretty does the same as as your manual enqueuing of tasks.